# VBA how to get the name of a variable and then pass it to a function

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, function, dictionary

I have have a sub which creates multiple empty arrays, resizes them, loops a large set of data and then calls a function to apply a value to one of the arrays.

The function which updates the arrays is called numerous times within the procedure, yet I am currently using multiple if statements to determine which array should be passed as a parameter. Therefore, I am trying to work out how I can pass the name of the array using either another function - which returns the name of the array, or a dictionary, where i can supply the key and the array name as the item.

**For the function idea:**

```
Call updateArray(getArrayName(criteria))

function getArrayName(byVal criteria as String) as String
     if criteria = "a" then getArrayName = "array1"
     ...
     if criteria = "z" then getArrayName = "array26"
End function
```

The calling sub does not recognize the value as a name of a variable, it just thinks it is a string, ie "array1" which then causes a debug, as a array is not actually passed into the updateArray function.

**For the dictionary idea:**

```
dim myDict as new scripting.dictionary
dict.add "a", array1
...
dict.add "z", array26

dim arrayKey as string
arrayKey = criteria

call myFunction(myDict(arrayKey))
```

when I pass the array name using the key/item to the function, an array is passed in with the correct dimensions (set earlier in the code) as i can use a debug.print to get the lbound and ubound values. However, once the function completes, the expected value has not updated in any array. When looking in the watch window during runtime, if I locate the array I am expecting to have been passed in, the value in the expected position does not update.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

**update:** as suggested, here is the code for myFunction.

I was keeping the above code quite simple to help explain my issue, as you can see, the real code requires more parameters.

A dictionary (which is created when sizing each array) that contains all the row and column positions of the array (the row number is accessed via the account var, the column number is accessed via the oppType var). There are numerous oppType categories in the main data set, however in the output array, some categories store either an FTE value, a USD value or both. Therefore, the catType var is also passed in to allow me to correctly identify the correct column.  e.g. the oppType could be "CC" the output data has 2 columns for this category "CC" and "CC USD". The fte value goes in the "CC" col, the $USD value goes in the "CC USD" col.

The loop in the main sub determines if the value is an FTE or USD value (boValue). The qData variant is the actual array that is passed in and updated.

```
Function updateLosArray(ByRef arrayPosDict As Dictionary, ByRef qData As Variant, _
                        ByVal account As String, ByVal oppType As String, ByVal boValue As Double, ByVal catType As String)

Dim accRow As Long, oppTypeCol As Long

'calculate the correct array row position
accRow = arrayPosDict(account)

'calculate correct array column position
If catType = "FTE" Then oppTypeCol = arrayPosDict(oppType)
If catType = "USD" Then oppTypeCol = arrayPosDict(oppType & " USD")

'update position value
qData(accRow, oppTypeCol) = qData(accRow, oppTypeCol) + boValue

End Function
```

As mentioned, at the moment, I use multiple If statements that call the function. This is an example for an FTE item:

```
If qtr = "Q1" Then updateLosArray arrayPosDict, q1Data, account, oppType, fte, "FTE"
If qtr = "Q2" Then updateLosArray arrayPosDict, q2Data, account, oppType, fte, "FTE"
...
If qtr = "Q100" Then updateLosArray arrayPosDict, q100Data, account, oppType, fte, "FTE"
```

my idea was, instead of having multiple Ifs, I could just have one line of code to call the function, so replace the hard coded array name with a variable that gets the correct name, eg using a dictionary where the qtr var is the key, and the q?Data array is the item.

e.g.

```
updateLosArray arrayPosDict, arrayNameDict(qtr), account, oppType, fte, "FTE"
```

Sorry this is quite long winded!
Thanks

Comment: Store the array from the dictionary in a variable, pass it to the relevant routine, then put it back in the dictionary (assuming you need that updated).

Comment: @Rory just tried this, it acted exactly as before, a correctly sized array is passed in, the correct position within the passed in array is updated, the function ends. In next iteration, I can see the array that should have been passed in still blank, and the position of array passed into the function has now been wiped and is blank. For now, i am sticking with multiple IFs.

Comment: You need to show us the code in myFunction so we can see where you are making mistakes.  There is nothing wrong with the dictionary code as you have shown it.